# How to pass instance on currently running MediaPlayer to another activity

Tags: android

In Android, I want to pass the reference of currently running MediaPlayer to another Activity.
So that if the MediaPlayer is playing a song, the below code gets executed.
In the below code, MyEqualizer is a different activity.
And MediaPlayer is running in a different Activity.

```
if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    Toast.makeText(MyEqualizer.this, "Song Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing ? Did you tried to implement it?

Comment: I created an Activity in which I'm a playing a song. From this activity I called another activity 'MyEqualizer' for using the equalizer settings. I tried saving audioSessionId and passing it using sharedPreferences, but session Id is not related to MediaPlayer instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for the MediaPlayer that can be accessed via [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) - so it would be easy to allow different Activities to interact with your service. Generating AIDL files is really simple and a great way to deal with your problem.

There is a really good tutorial about AIDL at [Linuxtopia](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html).

Comment: Tim, do you mind sharing a code snippet as to how this can be done using AIDL ?